# Error writing XML file in Python appeared AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dom'

Tags: python, xml, attributeerror

When I was writing xml, appeared this error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dom'
I don't know what to do...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfqXw.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. Your question doesn't follow the guidelines to ask a good question in the site. Please refer to [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to edit your question to add your code and errors in text  mode.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `import xml.dom.minidom`, You import `xml`. But, your certainly also use `xml` as a global variable. So, the global variable is hiding the imported module.

Use a different name for your variable, for instance `tree` or `xml_tree` are common choices.

Comment: I appreciate you !!